# treemap vs hashmap and sort in terms of memory usage

Tags: java, collections

I have a huge file in the format:

```
x a
y c
x d
z a
z s
y k
```

I want that the output will be *sorted* and in the form

```
x a,d
y c,k
z a,s,k
```

For this type of task a hash is the best:

The straightforward TreeMap solution would be this:

```
Map<String, StringBuilder> agg = Maps.newTreeMap();

while ((line = r.readLine()) != null) {

    String[] arr = line.split("\t");
            String key = arr[0];
            String value = arr[1];

    if(agg.containsKey(key)) {
            agg.get(key).append(",").append(value);
        }
        else {
            agg.put(key, new StringBuilder(value));
        }
    }

}
r.close();


System.out.println("Printing results");
FileWriter f = new FileWriter("out.txt");

for (String key : agg.keySet()) {
    f.write(key+"\t"+agg.get(key)+"\n");
}
```

Another option would be to use a hashmap, take the keyset, sort it and iterate over it.

The different part would be

```
    System.out.println("Sorting array");
    List<String> keys = Lists.newArrayList(agg.keySet());
            Collections.sort(keys);
        System.out.println("Printing results");
        FileWriter f = new FileWriter("out.txt");

        for (String key : keys) {
            f.write(key+"\t"+agg.get(key)+"\n");
        }
```

For me the big O is less important because it is a batch job.

For me the memory usage is much more important.

Which strategy is more efficient in terms of memory?

HashMap and the peek in the sort phase or the TreeMap approach

Comment: Most memory efficient would be to do a two pass...

Comment: Sorry, what is a two pass?

Comment: Pass 1: Scan the file for keys. Sort & store them in an separate file. In this pass you only have the keys in memory. Pass 2: Scan the keyfile, use 1 key and find all the values, then get the next key and get all values. Write the values as soon as you found them. Then have only one key and one value in memory.

Comment: This is a nice idea, but now the io would kill me

Comment: I don't know how 'huge' your file is, but you might try MemoryMappedFile. See: http://www.codeproject.com/Tips/683614/Things-to-Know-about-Memory-Mapped-File-in-Java

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it's a batch job, a `TreeMap` won't use extra memory like `HashMap`. `HashMap`s default load factor is I believe 0.75 (i.e. the map can be 75% full before the size is grown).

A `TreeMap` would be more straight forward too, provided the O(log n) (IIRC) doesn't become a bottle neck. If it does, you could use a `List` with your own `Tuple` object and a custom `Comparator`, but then you don't get a O(1) `get()`.

Comment: I agree. But Treemap has three extra pointers   Entry<K,V> left;
        Entry<K,V> right;
        Entry<K,V> parent; Isn't this expensive?

Comment: You'd have to try it out, that's 192-bits on a 64-bit computer. If you know the amount of keys you have in advance (at least approximately), you could use a `HashMap` with the initial capacity set to that value, and the load factor to 1. However, if the capacity is exceeded, the map will roughly double its size.

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang Generally the cost of pointers is insignificant compared to the data you're storing. In any case, `TreeMap` would only have two more pointers than `HashMap`, as `Map.Entry` keeps a pointer to the next entry in the bucket. In addition, if memory serves `HashMap`s are created with initial capacity to some power of two, even if you enter something else -- in that case, some rounding is performed to get a power of two.

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang Also, if you're willing to sacrifice performance you can actually create a `HashMap` that never grows (or will take a long time to do so) if you specify a large enough load factor. If you're on Java 8, this will degrade your performance to about `O(lg n)` (albeit better than `TreeMap`), while previous versions of Java will be left with `O(n)` performance. If you go this way, you're likely to get similar memory usage out of `HashMap` and `TreeMap`, as the same number of entries will be created . Not sure how/if array overhead will play into that.

Comment: @DavidMichaelGang If memory usage is a lot more important than performance, you could always go for the `List` way. You'd have the smallest memory print, but it would take longer.

Answer (score 2):

**HashMap** is not optimal in memory utilization, rather for specific operations. It is backed by an array, which is allocated on initialization and resized when its size reaches certain limits. Consequently, memory is allocated eagerly. Its size is always a power of 2, which is actually a computational optimization for faster bucket index calculation. As a result, the (unused) allocated memory may significantly surpass the actual memory used by your program.

**TreeMap** provides the optimal memory utilization, while having worse performance in get, add, remove operations comparing to the HashMap. This becomes more obvious by its constructor, which doesn't have any parameter that can affect its computational complexity. All its entries are lazily allocated and associated with the existing entries to form a tree.

Comment: HashMap's nodes are lighter than TreeMap's. I'm not sure there's that much of a difference at the end of the day.

Comment: @shmosel, I have no objection to your statement. So if we were comparing HashMap.Node to TreeMap.Entry, I would definitely agree with you. However, comparing HashMap to TreeMap makes the internal structure of each more important in memory consumption. This is why I believe that TreeMap's allocation laziness benefits over HashMap allocation eagerness.

Answer (score 1):

Since number of unique keys is unknown, and could be large, hash based approach may consume more memory if number of keys exceed the product of initial capacity of the hash table & its load factor. Because in such events capacity simply gets doubled increasing memory usage.