# TreeMap takes up same amount of memory as HashMap?

Tags: java

Conventional wisdom tells us that `TreeMap` is a more memory efficient data structure than `HashMap` [[1](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17708526/), [2](https://www.baeldung.com/java-treemap-vs-hashmap), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47340512/)]

> A Treemap can save memory (in comparison to HashMap) because it only uses the amount of memory needed to hold its items, unlike a HashMap which uses contiguous region of memory

but tests tell otherwise [e.g., [4](https://github.com/lemire/HashVSTree/blob/master/README.md)].

e.g., Below are results of inserting 1M key-values into a `HashMap` and `TreeMap`. The key is a `long` and value is a `String`. `L` is length of the `String`.

HashMap, L=100, order=Sequential:

| N | time(ms) | memory (bytes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100,000 | 97 | 21,048,640 |
| 200,000 | 472 | 42,097,216 |
| 300,000 | 887 | 62,097,216 |
| 400,000 | 1,424 | 84,194,368 |
| 500,000 | 2,127 | 104,194,368 |
| 600,000 | 2,985 | 124,194,368 |
| 700,000 | 4,041 | 144,194,368 |
| 800,000 | 5,186 | 168,388,672 |
| 900,000 | 6,478 | 188,388,672 |
| 1,000,000 | 7,971 | 208,388,672 |

TreeMap, L=100, order=Sequential:

| N | time(ms) | memory (bytes) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 100,000 | 118 | 20,800,048 |
| 200,000 | 585 | 41,600,048 |
| 300,000 | 1,239 | 62,400,048 |
| 400,000 | 2,166 | 83,200,048 |
| 500,000 | 3,415 | 104,000,048 |
| 600,000 | 4,910 | 124,800,048 |
| 700,000 | 6,668 | 145,600,048 |
| 800,000 | 8,707 | 166,400,048 |
| 900,000 | 11,059 | 187,200,048 |
| 1,000,000 | 13,648 | 208,000,048 |

I tried experimenting with different values of `L` (and as low as `L=1`) and using a random insertion order but get the same end result - `TreeMap` takes up same amount of memory as `HashMap`.

In theory, `TreeMap` should be taking approx. *at least* 25% less memory than `HashMap` due to `HashMap`'s 0.75 load factor (which means at least 25% of space is wasted by a `HashMap`) [[5](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10901821)] (think `L=1`)

What gives? Can anyone explain this?

Comment: Where does it tell us it use less memory?

Comment: Nowhere in [1] is there a claim that TreeMap is more, or less, memory efficient than HashMap.

Comment: Where is the code that produced those results? Did you read the comments in the JDK source code? It contains things like _"This map usually acts as a binned (bucketed) hash table, but when bins get too large, they are transformed into bins of TreeNodes"_ and _"Because TreeNodes are about twice the size of regular nodes, we use them only when bins contain enough nodes to warrant use (see TREEIFY_THRESHOLD)
"_

Comment: How are you calculating the values in your `memory` column?

Comment: @tgdavies memory calculation done using https://github.com/jbellis/jamm

Answer (score 6):

It's not clear where you're getting your "conventional wisdom," and it's certainly not claimed in the citation.  It is certainly not a conventional expectation.  Nevertheless, we can at least break down the memory consumption of these respective data structures.

I'm going to assume a 64-bit OpenJDK JVM with [CompressedOops](https://wiki.openjdk.org/display/HotSpot/CompressedOops) enabled (as it is by default), and look at the standard OpenJDK 21 implementations of both types.  This means every object has a minimum overhead of 12 bytes, and is rounded up to a multiple of 8 bytes, and object references are 4 bytes.  This is typical.  I'm also going to ignore all constant overhead, and consider only factors that scale linearly with the number of entries.

A TreeMap entry contains five object pointers (key, value, left, right, parent), and one boolean (for red-black coloring).  Each of those object pointers consumes four bytes, to make 33 bytes, which rounds up to 40.  (The worst case for padding, actually, since it's 1 mod 8.)  Those 40 bytes per entry are the only linear factors; there aren't any other objects.

A HashMap contains the hash table array, and the entry objects.  The entry objects (setting aside tree nodes, those are only used rarely) have three object pointers (key, value, next) and one int, the cached hash code; that makes 28 bytes which round up to 32.  The hash table array is more complicated: its size is at least the number of entries *divided* by 0.75 (so times 4/3) and rounded up to the nearest power of two (potentially doubling the size -- e.g. 33 -> 64).  That's just four bytes per bucket for the object pointer, so between 16n/3 and 32n/3 bytes.  We'll set aside the padding for that, since it's at most a constant.

So a TreeMap takes 40n+O(1) bytes, and a HashMap takes between 37.3n + O(1) and 42.7n + O(1) bytes.  That averages to 40n+O(1), which is approximately what you found -- they consume around the same amount of memory.

(It also ends up about the same on a 32-bit JVM, where the entry sizes are 32 for TreeMap and 24 for HashMap, and the arrays are the same, which averages 32 bytes/element for both.)